# how do add a project to source control within an existing solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently noticed that my ..LibraryTests project is not under source control:

[image]

When I try to do a checkin (by right clicking on the solution and pressing **check in**) it says that there are **No Pending Changes**. It's not seeing changes to the LibraryTests project because it is not under source control.

From my perspective:

1. The first project is under source control
2. The second project is not under source control
3. The solution itself does not seem to be under source control.

**How do I get the entire solution including the Tests project checked in?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you go into Source Control Explorer and navigate to your project you should see that LibraryTests isn't included. Right click on the folder, click on "Add items to folder..." then click on your project folder thats missing. Click next and this should add it to source control.